# Get list of count mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, left-join

I have 3 tables :

- Student (list)
- Session (list of extra courses)
- inscription (list of inscription to session for each student)

I want to display for each student the count of inscription (without date for now ^^)

Here my query :

```
SELECT 
 student.id,
 student.session_token AS available_token,
 count(inscription_student.id_inscription) AS nb_inscription_in_progress
FROM student
  LEFT JOIN inscription_student ON student.id = inscription_student.id_student_join
WHERE 1
```

It return only 1 result...
Where is the matter ?

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40fd198/5

Comment: Add `GROUP BY 1,2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It returns only 1 result... Where is the matter ?

Your query uses aggregate functions in the `select` clause but it has no `group by` clause: so all rows are aggregated into a single row, and random values are chosen for the student id and token.

You need to `group by` student, so you get one row per student:

```
select 
    s.id,
    s.session_token as available_token,
    count(i.id_inscription) as nb_inscription_in_progress
from student s
left join inscription_student i on s.id = i.id_student_join
group by s.id
```